# Keras: Functional API -- Layer Datatype Error

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, keras-layer

I am trying to separate each of the outputs of a `keras` `Conv2D` layer using a for loop, and then adding another layer to it through the `Functional API`, but I am getting a type error. The code is:

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Flatten, Dense, Dropout, Input, Activation
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, ZeroPadding2D
from keras.layers.merge import Add
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import cv2, numpy as np
import glob
import csv

def conv_layer:
    input = Input(shape=(3,224,224))
    k = 64
    x = np.empty(k, dtype=object)
    y = np.empty(k, dtype=object)
    z = np.empty(k, dtype=object)
    for i in range(0,k):
        x[i] = Conv2D(1, (3,3), data_format='channels_first', padding='same')(input)
        y[i] = Conv2D(1, (3,3), data_format='channels_first', padding='same')(x[i])
        z[i] = keras.layers.add([x[i], y[i]])
    out = Activation('relu')(z)
    model = Model(inputs, out, name='split-layer-model')

    return model
```

But, it is throwing the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vgg16-local-connections.py", line 352, in <module>
    model = VGG_16_local_connections()
  File "vgg16-local-connections.py", line 40, in VGG_16_local_connections
    out = Activation('relu')(z)
  File "/Users/klab/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 519, in __call__
    input_shapes.append(K.int_shape(x_elem))
  File "/Users/klab/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 409, in int_shape
    shape = x.get_shape()
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_shape'
```

So, the datatype of `z` does not match the one of the `Functional API`. How can I fix this? Any help will be deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I had defined `z[i]`-s as separate layers, I thought `z` would effectively be a stack of those `z[i]`-s. But, they basically had to be concatenated to make the stack I wanted,

```
z = keras.layers.concatenate([z[i] for i in range (0,k)], axis=1)
out = Activation('relu')(z)
```

Since I was using `data_format='channels_first'`, the concatenation was done with `axis=1`, but for the more common, `data_format='channels_last'`, the concatenation has to be done with `axis=3`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant:

```
out = Activation('relu')(z[k - 1])
```

Your code sets the whole vector `z` with all layers to be an input to `Activation` which Keras does not know how to handle.

Comment: Actually, I wanted the entire stack to have a ReLU activation, and I thought just calling `z` would be sufficient. I later realised my mistake and added `z = keras.layers.concatenate([z[i] for i in range (0,k)], axis=1)` before the line `out = Activation('relu')(z)`, and it worked perfectly.